# 2D game development with Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I tried to find some answers to a few questions I have about Unity3D games development. I want to create 2D mobile games.

The thing I really want to know is if I can create a mobile game for different platforms at one time (as cordova can build Android / iOS / Windows hybrid apps) and if I have to pay a license or something to do that.

I read that it is cross-platform but the official website doesnt give more info about how can you do it or the prerequisites to create them.

Comment: Why use Unity**3D** when creating 2D applications?

Comment: @LinusG. Unity3d has had a great 2D environment since around version 4. something.

Comment: @LinusG. because Corona has a "free version" but with some limitations. Corona pro is the one to go. And the other one is Cocos2d but with the only version i would be confortable is Cocos2d-js , and i really didnt found that much documentation or info about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need to purchase any licencing for those platforms. You will need to start paying when your annual turnover is high enough but I doubt you have to worry about that now. See here: https://unity3d.com/get-unity. Unless you make $100 000 a year off of Unity then you can deploy to all platforms for free. If you make that large amount you will have to purchase the pro licence and additional platform specific licences.

Comment: Thanks @Reasurria for your answer. I dont think i could make that much money, so its okey by now. So, as i see, there's no license for cross-platform building or any problems like with others framework. Am i right?

Comment: You are correct. This comes at the price of having the unity splash screen always present in all your applications.

Answer (score 0):

Unity builds on the Unity Player for mobile games, so as long as ur target platform can handle Unit Player, u can distribute ur game. U can see a current list on their website, but as I know, it supports all current platforms.

The compatibility between those platforms, are independent on development aspect. U create ur game with Unity and then set the target platform to deploy.

As for the licening, first of all Unity itself pro costs about 1024$, and every platform i think another 1024$ so u could first use the free version and after a bit of success easy upgrade to the pro version. On the other hand u can use the free version as long as u stay with ur yearly income under 100 000$

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create cross platform games for Android, windows and IOS etc. You don't necessarily have to buy license. you can use free unity3d but keep in mind there are certain things you are not allowed to change, such as startup splash screen. also if you reach revenue of 100k there is a fee. 
here is a link for license info you can find all the details https://unity3d.com/legal/eula